# No section numbering in scrbook

Tags: sectioning, numbering, chapters, koma-script, scrbook

I am using the `scrbook` class.

In some chapters, I have sections so the elements therein get numbered x.y.z where x denotes the numbering of the chapter, y the one of the section and z the one of the specific element within the section.

However, I also have chapters without sections and I don't want to have a single section title for the whole chapter. If I just use no section, the elements in the content get numbered x.0.z since there is no section.

How can I get rid of the 0 for the chapters without section, so to have a numbering

```
x.1
x.2
...
```

therein?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: With elements in the content you mean ... what? Subsections? Subsubsections?

Answer (score 3):

The zero section numbers can be omitted the following way, example for `equation`:

```
\renewcommand*{\theequation}{%
  \ifnum\value{section}=0 %
    \thechapter
  \else
    \thesection
  \fi
  .\arabic{equation}%
}
```

Comment: There's no `equation` mentioned in the OP

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The question refers to *elements*. I assume this means `figure`, `table`, `equation` or whatever the document uses. Since I cannot provide definitions for infinite element types, `equation` is just an *example*.

Comment: @clemens Usually the section number already includes the chapter number. If the document uses a different layout, then the example needs to be adjusted, of course.